# Capture a child process's stdout with libuv

Tags: c, spawn, libuv

I'm using libuv.  I've read http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/processes.html and still cannot work out how to capture the stdout of a child process so that it is available in the parent (but not in place of the parent's stdin).

My code is currently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../../libuv/include/uv.h"

uv_loop_t *loop;
uv_process_t child_req;
uv_process_options_t options;
uv_pipe_t apipe;

void on_child_exit(uv_process_t *req, int exit_status, int term_signal) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Process exited with status %d, signal %d\n", exit_status, term_signal);
    uv_close((uv_handle_t*) req, NULL);
}

uv_buf_t alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t *handle, size_t len) {
    printf("alloc_buffer called\n");
    uv_buf_t buf;
    buf.base = malloc(len);
    buf.len = len;
    return buf;
}

void read_apipe(uv_stream_t* stream, ssize_t nread, uv_buf_t buf) {
    printf("read %li bytes from the child process\n", nread);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("spawn_test\n");
    loop = uv_default_loop();

    char* args[3];
    args[0] = "dummy";
    args[1] = NULL;
    args[2] = NULL;

    uv_pipe_init(loop, &apipe, 0);
    uv_pipe_open(&apipe, 0);

    options.stdio_count = 3;
    uv_stdio_container_t child_stdio[3];
    child_stdio[0].flags = UV_IGNORE;
    child_stdio[1].flags = UV_INHERIT_STREAM;
    child_stdio[1].data.stream = (uv_stream_t *) &apipe;
    child_stdio[2].flags = UV_IGNORE;
    options.stdio = child_stdio;

    options.exit_cb = on_child_exit;
    options.file = args[0];
    options.args = args;

    uv_read_start((uv_stream_t*)&apipe, alloc_buffer, read_apipe);
    if (uv_spawn(loop, &child_req, options)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", uv_strerror(uv_last_error(loop)));
        return 1;
    }

    return uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

dummy.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("child starting\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("child running\n");
    sleep(2);
    printf("child ending\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have the nagging feeling that I do not quite understand the point of libuv's pipes yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the solution:

1. I had the wrong flags, they should have been `UV_CREATE_PIPE | UV_READABLE_PIPE` not `UV_INHERIT_STREAM`.
2. I needed to call `uv_read_start` after `uv_spawn`.  I assume that there's no chance of data loss, as uv_run has not yet been called.
3. The above two fixes showed all the output from `dummy` to arriving at once, rather than in three lumps (as it does on the command line).  An `fflush` in `dummy.c` fixed this.

spawn_test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../../libuv/include/uv.h"

uv_loop_t *loop;
uv_process_t child_req;
uv_process_options_t options;
uv_pipe_t apipe;

void on_child_exit(uv_process_t *req, int exit_status, int term_signal) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Process exited with status %d, signal %d\n", exit_status, term_signal);
    uv_close((uv_handle_t*) req, NULL);
}

uv_buf_t alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t *handle, size_t len) {
    printf("alloc_buffer called, requesting a %lu byte buffer\n");
    uv_buf_t buf;
    buf.base = malloc(len);
    buf.len = len;
    return buf;
}

void read_apipe(uv_stream_t* stream, ssize_t nread, uv_buf_t buf) {
    printf("read %li bytes in a %lu byte buffer\n", nread, buf.len);
    if (nread + 1 > buf.len) return;
    buf.base[nread] = '\0'; // turn it into a cstring
    printf("read: |%s|", buf.base);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("spawn_test\n");
    loop = uv_default_loop();

    char* args[3];
    args[0] = "dummy";
    args[1] = NULL;
    args[2] = NULL;

    uv_pipe_init(loop, &apipe, 0);
    uv_pipe_open(&apipe, 0);

    options.stdio_count = 3;
    uv_stdio_container_t child_stdio[3];
    child_stdio[0].flags = UV_IGNORE;
    child_stdio[1].flags = UV_CREATE_PIPE | UV_READABLE_PIPE;
    child_stdio[1].data.stream = (uv_stream_t *) &apipe;
    child_stdio[2].flags = UV_IGNORE;
    options.stdio = child_stdio;

    options.exit_cb = on_child_exit;
    options.file = args[0];
    options.args = args;

    if (uv_spawn(loop, &child_req, options)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", uv_strerror(uv_last_error(loop)));
        return 1;
    }
    uv_read_start((uv_stream_t*)&apipe, alloc_buffer, read_apipe);

    return uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

dummy.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("child starting\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    printf("child running\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(2);
    printf("child ending\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

See how they do it in the libuv unit test [libuv/test/test-stdio-over-pipes.c](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/test/test-stdio-over-pipes.c):

- Don't call `uv_pipe_open`
- Flags for child's stdin: `UV_CREATE_PIPE | UV_READABLE_PIPE`
- Flags for child's stdout and stderr: `UV_CREATE_PIPE | UV_WRITABLE_PIPE`

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/865) on Windows, where `uv_spawn` might return zero even though it encountered an error, and in those cases, you need to check `process.spawn_error`, which only exists on Windows.